# Modify the `Head`of a function

Tags: function-construction, formatting

I created a function `HInt`that gives me a traditional output for integrates.

```
HInt/:MakeBoxes[HInt[f_,{x_,x1_}],StandardForm]:=RowBox[{SubscriptBox["\[Integral]",ToBoxes[x1]],ToBoxes[f],"\[DoubleStruckD]",ToBoxes[x]}]
```

Example:

```
HInt[f, {v, V}]
```

[image]

Now I created a function `HIntTogether` that unifies two integrates with the same domain.

```
HIntTogether/:MakeBoxes[HIntTogether[HInt[f_,{v_,V_}]+HInt[g_,{s_,S_}]]/;(v==s&&V==S),StandardForm]:=RowBox[{MakeBoxes[HInt[f+g,{v,V}]]}]
```

Example:

```
HIntTogether[HInt[f, {v, V}] + HInt[g, {v, V}]]
```

[image]

The problem is: When I look at the `FullForm`of the result I have:

[image]

But the `Head` of the result that I want is some like a new integrate:

```
HInt[Plus[f,g],{v,V}]
```

Some like this. How to change the `Head`of the result applying the function `HIntTogether`?

Comment: What you did for `HIntTogether` is a definition of how it will be typeset and then displayed. The result of evaluation or % or Out[] don't know about that. If you want `HIntTogether` to evaluate to merged version then don't define it for `MakeBoxes`.

Comment: You are right @Kuba. Thanks. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = HIntTogether[...]
```

`result` will contain the result of evaluation of `HIntTogether[...]`. `Out[]`/`%` also refer to the result of evaluation.

And during evaluation nothing really happend because your code defines typesetting of your expressions. Only for display purposes. Here's the sequence, roughly:

> input -> parsing -> evaluation -> formatting -> typesetting -> rendering

Please read:

- tutorial/TheMainLoop
- tutorial/WolframSystemSessions

And related tutorials.